# Converting Pseudocode to SQL Script

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

So I have two tables:

1. `Bookmarks` has a few columns [id, etc.]
2. `Person_Bookmark` has 2 columns [personId, bookmarkId]

`Bookmarks` represents links to other websites. All valid bookmarks have an id. The `Person_Bookmark` table has a bunch of `personIds` and their bookmarks, shown as `bookmarkId`.

Here's my pseudocode:

```
> let x = integer list of all bookmarkId's from Person_Bookmark
> 
> for each x  {   
>     if ('select * from 'Bookmarks' where 'id' = x returns 0 rows) {
>       delete from 'person_bookmark' where 'bookmarkId' = x
>     }
> }
```

Please advise me how to convert to a Postgres [edit] SQL script.

Comment: You didn't specify the target dialect of SQL. Still, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859759/sql-iterating-over-a-list-to-call-exec-on-each-item

Comment: For starters, think about "sets" instead of "algorithms" :)  Book recommendation: [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Queries-Mere-Mortals-Hands-/dp/0201433362)

Comment: Pseudocode is nice, but you really need to state what you want to achieve in plain English, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Jan mentioned *foreign keys* already, but his advice is incomplete.

Seems like you want to delete all associations to a bookmark that does not exist (any more).
Define a [**foreign key constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) in the form of:

```
ALTER TABLE person_bookmarks
ADD CONSTRAINT pb_fk FOREIGN KEY (bookmarkid) REFERENCES bookmarks (id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

- This only allows values in `person_bookmarks.bookmarkid` that exist in `bookmarks.id`.
- `ON UPDATE CASCADE` changes corresponding *values* in `person_bookmarks.bookmarkid` when you change an entry in `bookmarks.id`
- `ON DELETE CASCADE` deletes corresponding *rows* in `person_bookmarks.bookmarkid` when you change an entry in `bookmarks.id`.

Other options are available, [read the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

The `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause does *automatically*, what you are trying to fix manually. Before you can add the fk constraint you'll have to fix it manually once:

```
DELETE FROM person_bookmarks pb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookmarks b WHERE b.id = pb.bookmarkid);
-- OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM persons p   WHERE p.id = pb.personid);
```

Deletes all rows with non-existing `bookmarkid`. Uncomment the last line to get rid of dead persons, too.

Comment: Erwin - thank you for the detailed explanation. From an architecture perspective, is there a debate as to whether foreign key constraints should be used instead of the software being responsible for making required changes?

Comment: Foreign keys maintain referential integrity under all circumstances, as fail-safe it it gets. They are a proven solution at the core of the RDBMS. Any solution in client software is bound to fail sooner or later. Think of disrupted connections, concurrency (race conditions) of direct access to the database circumventing the client software.

Answer (score 2):

This works in SQL Server - not sure about MySQL...

```
delete pb
from
  person_bookmark pb
where not exists (select 1 from booksmarks b where b.id = pb.bookmarkid)
```

Comment: The question is actually tagged with PostgreSQL. But it's standard SQL and should indeed work in any DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of @Derek's reply:

```
DELETE FROM person_bookmark 
WHERE bookmarkid NOT IN (SELECT id FROM bookmarks)
```

The need to do this implies that you have no foreign key indexes between your tables. I strongly advise you to do so. The drawback (or feature) lies in that when you for example delete a `person` (I'm guessing this table exists from your example), you have to delete all associated data first, otherwise the server will throw an error.

Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM person_Bookmark WHERE personid = @personid
DELETE FROM person_SomeOtherTable WHERE personid = @personid
DELETE FROM person WHERE id = @personid
```

The advantage though is that you'll have no orphan rows in your database, and you can't enter erroneous data by mistake (store  a `bookmark` for a `person` that doesn't exist).